# How set @ServerTimestamp annotation in custom object classes - Firestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I have a field in the Firestore database that is TimeStamp and is in this format: *Quarta-feira, 11 de Outubro de 2017 às 10:24:54 GMT-03:00*

It is defined as: **map.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());**

According to Firestore instructions, you need to add a annotation, directly to the model class.

I have in my class the TimeStamp field in String. I tried using TimeStamp and it does not work

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Code Class Model:

```
public class Servicos {

        private String nome_produto;
        private String duracao;
        private String valor;
        private String valor_old;
        private String categoria;
        private String categoria_nome;
        private String sub_categoria;
        private String sub_categoria_nome;
        private String descricao;
        private String duracao_milis;
        private String timestamp;

        public Servicos() {
        }

        public Servicos(String nome_produto, String duracao, String valor, String valor_old,
                        String categoria, String categoria_nome, String sub_categoria, String sub_categoria_nome,
                        String descricao, String duracao_milis, String timestamp){

            this.nome_produto = nome_produto;
            this.duracao = duracao;
            this.valor = valor;
            this.valor_old = valor_old;
            this.categoria = categoria;
            this.categoria_nome = categoria_nome;
            this.duracao_milis = duracao_milis;
            this.sub_categoria = sub_categoria;
            this.sub_categoria_nome = sub_categoria_nome;
            this.descricao = descricao;
            this.timestamp = timestamp;

        }

        public String getNome_produto() {
            return nome_produto;
        }

        public void setNome_produto(String nome_produto) {
            this.nome_produto = nome_produto;
        }

        public String getDuracao() {
            return duracao;
        }

        public void setDuracao(String duracao) {
            this.duracao = duracao;
        }

        public String getValor() {
            return valor;
        }

        public void setValor(String valor) {
            this.valor = valor;
        }

        public String getValor_old() {
            return valor_old;
        }

        public void setValor_old(String valor_old) {
            this.valor_old = valor_old;
        }

        public String getCategoria() {
            return categoria;
        }

        public void setCategoria(String categoria) {
            this.categoria = categoria;
        }

        public String getCategoria_nome() {
            return categoria_nome;
        }

        public void setCategoria_nome(String categoria_nome) {
            this.categoria_nome = categoria_nome;
        }

        public String getSub_categoria() {
            return sub_categoria;
        }

        public void setSub_categoria(String sub_categoria) {
            this.sub_categoria = sub_categoria;
        }

        public String getSub_categoria_nome() {
            return sub_categoria_nome;
        }

        public void setSub_categoria_nome(String sub_categoria_nome) {
            this.sub_categoria_nome = sub_categoria_nome;
        }

        public String getDescricao() {
            return descricao;
        }

        public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
            this.descricao = descricao;
        }

        public String getDuracao_milis() {
            return duracao_milis;
        }

        public void setDuracao_milis(String duracao_milis) {
            this.duracao_milis = duracao_milis;
        }

        public String getTimestamp() {
            return timestamp;
        }

        public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
        }
    }
```

Ref Firestore Documentation: [Link Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/update-data)

```
// If you're using custom Java objects in Android, add an @ServerTimestamp
// annotation to a Date field for your custom object classes. This indicates
// that the Date field should be treated as a server timestamp by the object mapper.

DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("objects").document("some-id");

// Update the timestamp field with the value from the server
Map<String,Object> updates = new HashMap<>();
updates.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

docRef.update(updates).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    // ...
    // ...
```

Comment: check this link may solve your problem
[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47035245/how-to-use-fieldvalue-servertimestamp-to-custom-model-class-in-android)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example of how to use `ServerTimestamp` with a custom Java class:

```
public class Rating {

    private String userId;
    private @ServerTimestamp Date timestamp;

    public Rating() {}

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

     public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Been looking for this for a long time.  Perfect fix, thanks.

Comment: One important thing is that if you are using *offline* functionality,  and you have the field timestamp on null,  the server will put the time automatically when the connection is enabled and the DB is synced, and not when the object was created and saved.

If the app is designed to be always online,  then there is no problem because the time will be set to the server time automatically

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Klass {
    private Date timestamp;

    public Klass() {}

    @ServerTimestamp
    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```