# how to use FieldValue.serverTimestamp() to custom model class in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore as a database and now i want to store server timestamp when user register.

from the Firestore doc

```
  Map<String,Object> updates = new HashMap<>();
  updates.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
  docRef.update(updates)
  .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {  //-- }
```

But now i want this time stamp in my model class.

```
public class UserModel implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String uid;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private long timestamp;

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

how can i achieve this. 
Please help me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After lots of research i found a solution for this.

```
 @ServerTimestamp
 private Date timestamp;

 public Date getTimestamp() {
     return timestamp;
 }
 public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
 }
```

and when calling this class

```
UserModel userModel = new UserModel();
userModel.setEmail(email);
userModel.setPassword(password);
userModel.setName(name);
userModel.setUid(uid);

insertUserDataToFireStore(userModel);
```

This is the link where i found the solution
[Click here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/ServerTimestamp)

Comment: How can I achieve something like that in iOS? How can I create model class that contain timestamp data type?

Comment: Thank you! Shouldn't the @ServerTimestamp annotation be on the public getter instead of the private member?

Comment: Thx for after 4 hours of struggle you saved my day. +1

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line of code:

```
private long timestamp;
```

with

```
private Map<String, String> timestamp;
```

And here are the corresponding public `setters` and `getters`:

```
public void setTimestamp(Map<String, String> timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
public Map<String, String> getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}
```

Remember, that you are setting the timestamp as `Map` and when you are retrieving, you are retrieving it as a `Long`.

Comment: Why is this so complicated? I'm trying to have a simple getter in my custom class and there is nothing on this on the web and when I asked for help I got shut down here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60480508/get-timestamp-from-firebase-pojo And no, none of the examples here works for me - nor `Map<String, String>` nor `@ServerTimestamp` annotation. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @jeand'arme I suggest you take some time and read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). So please post another fresh question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
private com.google.firebase.Timestamp date;

public yourModel(com.google.firebase.Timestamp date) {
        this.date= date;
}

public com.google.firebase.Timestamp getDate() {
        return date;
}

public void setDate(com.google.firebase.Timestamp date) {
        this.date = date;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you only want a ***timestamp*** and not an accurate time event then you can use

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
```