# How to use FieldValue.serverTimestamp() as Model class in iOS - swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore as a database and now i want to store server timestamp when user register. This question is opposite of [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47035245/how-to-use-fieldvalue-servertimestamp-to-custom-model-class-in-android)

```
FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

This is model class

```
struct NotificationModel: Identifiable, Codable {
   var id: String? = nil
   var title: String?
   var body: String?
   var timestamp: Date?

   init(title: String, body: String, timestamp: Date) {
       self.title = title
       self.body = body
       self.timestamp = timestamp
   } 
}
```

I want this time stamp in my model class.

How can I achieve something like this?

```
.document(ID).collection("notifications").order(by: "timestamp", descending: true).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
```

This is whole code which i `decode` document from `Firestore` to Json

```
func readUserNotifications<T: Decodable>(from collectionReference: FIRCollectionReference, get userId: String, returning objectType: T.Type, fromType collectionCell: FIRCollectionCell, completion: @escaping ([T], _ sucess: Bool) -> Void)  {


    collectionReferences(to: collectionReference).document(userId).collection("notifications").order(by: "timestamp", descending: true).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
        var objectsAppend = [T]()
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
            print("Doesn't have snapshot")
            return
        }
        do {
            for document in snapshot.documents {

                //print(try document.decode(as: NotificationModel.self))
                let object = try document.decode(as: objectType.self, includingId: true)
                objectsAppend.append(object)
            }
            if objectsAppend.isEmpty {
                objectsAppend.removeAll()
                completion(objectsAppend, false)
            } else {
                completion(objectsAppend, true)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my `decode` function that error in there

```
extension DocumentSnapshot {

func decode<T: Decodable>(as objectType: T.Type, includingId: Bool = true) throws  -> T {

    var documentJson = data()
    if includingId {

        documentJson["id"] = documentID
    }

    let documentData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: documentJson, options: [])
    let decodedObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(objectType, from: documentData)

    return decodedObject
}
```

}

Comment: "Not work" is pretty imprecise. What happens when you issue this query?

Comment: Opp i forgot to add more. I haven't add `timestamp` to `Firestore` programmatically yet. Instead of adding by myself in firestore document and when i query i want to set data to my Model class but unable to decode it because the of data type of `timestamp` that i declare in class not applicable.

Comment: I want `timestamp` in my model class

Comment: The question is a bit unclear; are you asking how to store and read a timestamp using Firestore? Or how to [timestamp your document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)? Did you review [areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabledset](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/FirestoreSettings#/c:objc(cs)FIRFirestoreSettings(py)timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled). The object you are calling a *model class* is actually defined as a struct but what's preventing a timestamp from being added?

Comment: @Jay My question is that! I have timestamp in firestore So, how can I retrieve it to store in model class. Because i could not find data type in swift that fitable with timestamp in firestore document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: assume we have a Firestore structure of this (as shown in the Firestore console)

```
timestamps
   stamp_0
      stamp: September 18, 2018 at 8:00:00 AM UTC-4
   stamp_1
      stamp: September 18, 2018 at 8:01:00 AM UTC-4
   stamp_2
      stamp: September 18, 2018 at 8:02:00 AM UTC-4
```

and we want to read the timestamps and print the key and the formatted timestamp to console.

```
self.db.collection("timestamps").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
    } else {
        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            if let stamp = document.get("stamp") {
                let title = document.documentID
                let ts = stamp as! Timestamp
                let aDate = ts.dateValue()
                let formatter = DateFormatter()
                formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"
                let formattedTimeZoneStr = formatter.string(from: aDate)
                print(title, formattedTimeZoneStr)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the output is

```
stamp_0 2018-09-18 08:00:00 -0400
stamp_1 2018-09-18 08:01:00 -0400
stamp_2 2018-09-18 08:02:00 -0400
```

That's how you get to the timestamp data.

Storing it in your model class could be done in a number of ways depending on what you want to do with it: it could be stored as a formatted timestamp string (as shown in my answer), or a Firestore Timestamp object or a Date (NSDate) object. Just depends on your use case.

[Timestamp API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Timestamp)

Comment: thank for your explanation but it throws me error for `document.get("stamp")`  is that `Value of type 'DocumentSnapshot' has no member 'get'`

Comment: @VisalSambo Make sure you are running XCode 10 and have updated the current version of Firebase. That code came straight out of a working project and I just ran it again with no errors.

Comment: @VisalSambo and here's the documentation for the [get](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentSnapshot#get_) function.

Comment: Thank for you time bro!

Comment: @VisalSambo My pleasure. Be sure to accept the answer if it helped you so it can also help others!